# extracting br tags beautiful soup python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to web scraping. I am trying to extract the address text "Tegelhof 1 33014 Bad Driburg" and " Tegelweg 2A 33014 Bad Driburg" from the below html code which is in br tags. But I don't get the desired results. I have used below code so far to get but there is no success. Can someone help me how to

code:

```py
address = [soup.find('div', class_='col-sm-4 pt-2')
```

Full Source code:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5 py-2">
        <br/>
        <span style="color:#7fb7c4; font-weight:600;">Praxis jetzt geöffnet</span>
        <p class="mt-5 d-none d-md-block">Telefon: <a class="it" href="tel:+4952531717">0 52 53 / 17 17</a></p>
    </div>
    <!-- sm-5 end -->
    <div class="col-sm-4 pt-2">
        <!-- <img class="mapicons" src="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/images/GoogleImages/A.png" alt=" " /><br>  -->
        <br/>
        <img alt=" " src="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/img/entfernung.svg"/>  0.2 km<br/>
        <span class="pt-3 d-none d-md-block"></span>
        Tegelhof 1<br/>
        33014 Bad Driburg<br/>
    </div><!-- sm-4 end -->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    </div><!-- sm-3 end -->
</div><!--   end row  -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5 py-2">
        <br/>
        <span style="color:#7fb7c4; font-weight:600;">Praxis jetzt geöffnet</span>
        <p class="mt-5 d-none d-md-block">Telefon: <a class="it" href="tel:+4952536565">0 52 53 / 65 65</a></p>
    </div><!-- sm-5 end -->
    <div class="col-sm-4 pt-2">
        <!-- <img class="mapicons" src="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/images/GoogleImages/A.png" alt=" " /><br>  -->
        <br/>
        <img alt=" " src="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/img/entfernung.svg"/>  0.2 km<br/>
        <span class="pt-3 d-none d-md-block"></span>
        Tegelweg 2A<br/>
        33014 Bad Driburg<br/>
    </div><!-- sm-4 end -->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    </div><!-- sm-3 end -->
</div><!--   end row  -->
```

Comment: i have tried to select the `<br>` tags, but their text is `empty`.

Comment: `[<br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>]`

Comment: you cant find the content of this `br`s because they are not `opening`, they are just `closing tags` and beautiful soup doesnt consider them a tag

Comment: From [w3ressource](https://www.w3resource.com/html/br/HTML-br-tag-and-element.php) "br element can not contain any content by itself."

Comment: What is the output you obtain from your code ? It should display the text you are searching for. Try `soup.find_all('div', class_='col-sm-4 pt-2')[0].text` (i suggest you use `find_all` which returns every matched tags instead of the first one only).

Comment: `address = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-sm-4 pt-2')
[i.text for i in address]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
html_doc="""<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-5 py-2">
 <br/><span style="color:#7fb7c4; font-weight:600;">Praxis jetzt geöffnet</span>
 <p class="mt-5 d-none d-md-block">Telefon: <a class="it" href="tel:+4952531717">0 52 53 / 17 17</a></p>
 </div><!-- sm-5 end -->
 <div class="col-sm-4 pt-2">
 <!-- <img class="mapicons" src="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/images/GoogleImages/A.png" alt=" " /><br>  -->
 <br/>
 <img alt=" " src="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/img/entfernung.svg"/>  0.2 km<br/>
 <span class="pt-3 d-none d-md-block"></span>
 Tegelhof 1<br/>
 33014 Bad Driburg<br/>
 </div><!-- sm-4 end -->
 <div class="col-sm-3">
 </div><!-- sm-3 end -->
 </div><!--   end row  -->

 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-5 py-2">
 <br/><span style="color:#7fb7c4; font-weight:600;">Praxis jetzt geöffnet</span>
 <p class="mt-5 d-none d-md-block">Telefon: <a class="it" href="tel:+4952536565">0 52 53 / 65 65</a></p>
 </div><!-- sm-5 end -->
 <div class="col-sm-4 pt-2">
 <!-- <img class="mapicons" src="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/images/GoogleImages/A.png" alt=" " /><br>  -->
 <br/>
 <img alt=" " src="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/img/entfernung.svg"/>  0.2 km<br/>
 <span class="pt-3 d-none d-md-block"></span>
 Tegelweg 2A<br/>
 33014 Bad Driburg<br/>
 </div><!-- sm-4 end -->
 <div class="col-sm-3">
 </div><!-- sm-3 end -->
 </div><!--   end row  --> """
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
address = soup.find_all('div', class_='col-sm-4 pt-2')
[i.text for i in address]
```

Output:

```
['\n\n\n  0.2 km\n\n Tegelhof 1\n 33014 Bad Driburg\n',
 '\n\n\n  0.2 km\n\n Tegelweg 2A\n 33014 Bad Driburg\n']
```

Instead of `find` use `findall` to get a list of and use `text` method to get just the text part.

Update:

```
add1=[i.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip(' ')  for i in address]
```

Using `replace` to replace `\n` with `space` and stripping all extra spaces
Output:

```
['0.2 km   Tegelhof 1  33014 Bad Driburg',
 '0.2 km   Tegelweg 2A  33014 Bad Driburg']

add2=[i.partition('km') for i in add1]
[[i[0]+i[1],i[2].strip(' ')] for i in add2]
```

Output:

```
[['0.2 km', 'Tegelhof 1  33014 Bad Driburg'],
 ['0.2 km', 'Tegelweg 2A  33014 Bad Driburg']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I originally had the solution to get just the address since that's what you asked, but however you can separate the other text from that text if you want both:

```
import re 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-5 py-2">
 <br/><span style="color:#7fb7c4; font-weight:600;">Praxis jetzt geöffnet</span>
 <p class="mt-5 d-none d-md-block">Telefon: <a class="it" href="tel:+4952531717">0 52 53 / 17 17</a></p>
 </div><!-- sm-5 end -->
 <div class="col-sm-4 pt-2">
 <!-- <img class="mapicons" src="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/images/GoogleImages/A.png" alt=" " /><br>  -->
 <br/>
 <img alt=" " src="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/img/entfernung.svg"/>  0.2 km<br/>
 <span class="pt-3 d-none d-md-block"></span>
 Tegelhof 1<br/>
 33014 Bad Driburg<br/>
 </div><!-- sm-4 end -->
 <div class="col-sm-3">
 </div><!-- sm-3 end -->
 </div><!--   end row  -->

 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-5 py-2">
 <br/><span style="color:#7fb7c4; font-weight:600;">Praxis jetzt geöffnet</span>
 <p class="mt-5 d-none d-md-block">Telefon: <a class="it" href="tel:+4952536565">0 52 53 / 65 65</a></p>
 </div><!-- sm-5 end -->
 <div class="col-sm-4 pt-2">
 <!-- <img class="mapicons" src="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/images/GoogleImages/A.png" alt=" " /><br>  -->
 <br/>
 <img alt=" " src="https://www.tk-aerztefuehrer.de/TK/img/entfernung.svg"/>  0.2 km<br/>
 <span class="pt-3 d-none d-md-block"></span>
 Tegelweg 2A<br/>
 33014 Bad Driburg<br/>
 </div><!-- sm-4 end -->
 <div class="col-sm-3">
 </div><!-- sm-3 end -->
 </div><!--   end row  -->'''
 
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')

divs = soup.find_all('div', {'class':re.compile(r'pt-2')})
for div in divs:
    text_list = div.text.strip().split('\n')
    km = text_list[0]
    address = ' '.join([x for x in text_list[1:] if x !='']).strip()
    print(km)
    print(address)
```

**Output:**

```
0.2 km
Tegelhof 1  33014 Bad Driburg
0.2 km
Tegelweg 2A  33014 Bad Driburg
```